# Upon importing a CSV file, any rows containing "E2" are being entered into the database as 00

Tags: php, encoding, insert

I'm doing a CSV import with Laravel, one specific column is giving me grief. Here is one of the offending rows:

**..."Smith, John",John,Smith,11E2,"06 Jun 2007",F,,No,No,No,...**

The "11E2" is being entered as 1100 into my varchar column in mySql.

Here are some steps I tried to figure out where this issue is occurring:

[image]

At step one, I did a dump to see how the data was formatted, here is the result:

[image]

Great - the data looks correct so far.

On step two, the import:

[image]

I get:

[image]

Here is the StudentsImport file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use App\Models\Student;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithUpserts;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\HeadingRowImport;

class StudentsImport implements ToModel, WithHeadingRow, WithUpserts
{

    /**
     * @return string|array
     */
    public function uniqueBy()
    {
        return 'upn';
    }


    /**
     * @param array $row
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
     */

    public function model(array $row)
    {

        $current = Student::where('upn', $row['upn'])->first();

        /*if($row['last_name']=="Smith"){
            dd($row);
        }*/

        if(!$current){
            $user = new Student();
        }
        else{
            $user = $current;
        }

        //Get year from form group colum as arbor doesnt have some students with a year group
        if(str_starts_with($row['registration_forms_this_academic_year'], '1')){
            $row['year'] = substr($row['registration_forms_this_academic_year'], 0, 2);
        }else{
            $row['year'] = substr($row['registration_forms_this_academic_year'], 0, 1);
        }



        $user->first_name = $row['first_name'];
        $user->last_name = $row['last_name'];
        $user->year = $row['year'];
        $user->date_of_birth = $row['date_of_birth'];
        $user->registration_forms_this_academic_year = $row['registration_forms_this_academic_year'];

        $user->sex = $row['sex'];
        $user->looked_after_in_care_status = $row['looked_after_in_care_status'];
        $user->ever_6_fsm_at_any_time_this_academic_year = $row['pupil_premium_eligible_at_any_time_this_academic_year'];
        $user->eal_at_any_time_this_academic_year = $row['eal_at_any_time_this_academic_year'];
        $user->coursesclasses = $row['coursesclasses'];
        $user->upn = $row['upn'];
        $user->student_number = $row['student_number'];
        $user->ppm = $row['ppm'];
        $user->school_history = $row['school_history'];

        $code = null;
        if($row['sen_status_for_today'][0]=="N"){
            $code = "M";
        }else{
            $code = $row['sen_status_for_today'][0];
        }

        $user->send_status_code = $code;


        $user->created_at = now();
        $user->updated_at = now();

        return $user;
    }
}
```

I assume some conversion is happening here because PHP is presuming this is a number? I tried wrapping that column in the csv with quotes, but this did not solve the issue. Do I have to somehow force this as a string? If so, how would I go about doing that?

I hope I was clear in my explanation.

EDIT: For clarification, the $upload going into the StudentsImport() is the csv file itself:

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Like https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting?

Comment: Though casting would only change the output of the data. "_The "11E2" is being entered as 1100 into my varchar column in mySql._" You said it is being inserted into your database as `1100`, so that probably won't help much

Comment: @brombeer - The data has been converted to 1100 before the insert happens: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRaOa.png

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, from a reply on github:

"PhpSpreadsheet detected 11E2 as a number (11^2) so it makes sense it inserts as 1100. If you want to prevent that, you'll have to tell PhpSpreadsheet that that column is not a number. You can do so via a value binder, or if you want everything to be a string you can use the stringvaluebinder"

This fixed it:

```
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\StringValueBinder;

class StudentsImport extends StringValueBinder implements WithCustomValueBinder, ToModel, WithHeadingRow, WithUpserts
{
```

Comment: For any future question you post, please include all relevant information - like using `PhpSpreadsheet`, which you didn't mention in your question at all

Comment: Apologies @brombeer. I was not aware that I was using this package, it must that Maatwebsite/Excel uses it as a dependency